# Nested dictionary with multiple verbs which in turn have multiple verbs inside. I want to recall a verb, but I have an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

With this code I would like to print `Jessica è chiamata alla prova del tris`, then recall from the dictionary first the word "chiamare", then check whether to use the word "è chiamata" through the for loop (because Jessica is a feminine name and therefore there is the "a" "è chiamatA").

The use of that for loop is important, so if you want to help me, try to stick to it and stay on that loop by modifying it as little as possible, because the loop first checks which is the subject and then in relation to the subject checks which word to use by looking for it in the dictionaries. I just call it with `{verb}`.

Previously I only needed to call it with `{verb}`, because in the dictionary I had two separate words like "è chiamata" and "è chiamato". It worked fine. Now, however, I have grouped these two verbs into a single verb which is "to call".

**PROBLEM**
So now if I try to print, it just prints `alla prova del tris` (without her she is called or called).

So I thought it takes some way to make it clear that I would like to recall the word "chiamare" and then check which one to use "è chiamata" or "è chiamato". So I tried to use `{verb ['chiamare']}`, but it obviously doesn't work, I know. Only later did I read why I can't use this, so let's avoid dwelling on why I don't have to write like this. Let's think about solving

**WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR?**
So what I would like is: in the sentence recall "call" to let him choose whether to use "is called" or is called. "To choose you need my for loop because you must first relate it to the subject. I'll write you what I want to do in order: the for loop relates the subject and the verb. She sees that Jessica's dictionary says it's feminine and singular, so the for loop uses the verb "è chiamatA" because this verb in the dictionary is feminine and singular. The for loop works correctly. But now that I have added the verb "chiamare" which encloses the 2 verbs "è chiamato" or "è chiamata", the project no longer works. So I thought there was a need to indicate that I wanted to invoke the verb "to call" using {verb ['to call']}, but of course it doesn't work.

So how could I fix it?

**IMPORTANT: before checking inside "chiamare" whether to use "è chiamato" or "è chiamata", remember that I first check the subject with the cycle, because thanks to the cycle I put in relation subject and verb. So my cycle I use is important**

Can you help me? Thank you

```
Name = {
"Jessica": {"gender" : "female", "quantity" : "singular"},
"David" : {"gender" : "male", "quantity" : "singular"}
}


dictionary_verbs = { "chiamare": {"è chiamata" : { "gender" : "female", "quantity" : "singular"},
                             "è chiamato" : { "gender" : "male", "quantity" : "singular"}},
                 #"other_verb": ...
                 #"other_verb": ...
                }

                         
  
subject = "Jessica"

#Search verb in relation to the subject
verb = ""
for key, value in dictionary_verbs.items():
    if Name[subject] == value:
        verb = key
        break


phrase = (f"{verb['chiamare']} alla prova del tris")

print(phrase)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work for your usecase.

```py
Name = {
"Jessica": {"gender" : "female", "quantity" : "singular"},
"David" : {"gender" : "male", "quantity" : "singular"}
}


dictionary_verbs = { "chiamare": {"è chiamata" : { "gender" : "female", "quantity" : "singular"},"è chiamato" : { "gender" : "male", "quantity" : "singular"}},
                 #"other_verb": ...
                 #"other_verb": ...
                }

subject = "Jessica"
#Search verb in relation to the subject
verb = {}
for key, value in dictionary_verbs.items():
    for nested_k,nested_v in value.items():
        if Name[subject] == nested_v:
            verb[key] = nested_k
            break

phrase = (f"{subject} {verb['chiamare']} alla prova del tris")

print(phrase)
```

Adding the following explanation for the discussion in comments:
Following is your code:

```
for key, value in dictionary_verbs.items():
    #variable value here contains this whole nested dictionary **{"è chiamata" : { "gender" : "female", "quantity" : "singular"},"è chiamato" : { "gender" : "male", "quantity" : "singular"}** 

    #what your code is comparing is {"gender" : "female", "quantity" : "singular"} from Name dictionary for key "jessica" with the value variable as mentioned above which will never match and the loop will never break,

    if Name[subject] == value:
        verb = key
        break
```

```
for key, value in dictionary_verbs.items():
    for nested_k,nested_v in value.items():
        """
        values for nested_k are "è chiamata" and "è chiamato" in subsequent iteration;
        values for nested_v are {"gender" : "female", "quantity" : "singular"} and { "gender" : "male", "quantity" : "singular"} respectively, which can be matched with "Name" dictionary
        """
        if Name[subject] == nested_v:
            verb[key] = nested_k
            # key = chiamare
            # nested_key = è chiamata or è chiamato
            break
```

I would suggest using a different structure/format for the "dictionary_verbs" dictionary if possible. More nested the dictionary is more for-loops will be added and if its a large dictionary it will simply add too much time complexity.

Also in the code, we introduce a new "verb" dictionary so that we can use it to print the "phrase" later in the code. If dictionary_verbs is a large dictionary verbs dictionary also will be large and take up more space.

Comment: Thank you. What is your loop for nested_k, nested_v in value.items () for? What do you mean by "If the format of the dictionary cant be changed, and you are not looking for optimizing time or space complexity this will print what you are looking for"? Thank you

Comment: dictionary_verbs is a nested dictionary.
You were trying to compare value for the key "Jesscia" from Names dictionary  {"gender" : "female", "quantity" : "singular"} with value like 
 {"è chiamata" : { "gender" : "female", "quantity" : "singular"},"è chiamato" : { "gender" : "male", "quantity" : "singular"}, it contains more than 1 dictionary. You would need to loop again to have the check in place.

Comment: we are creating a new verb dictionary just to print it outside the for loop. Can it be printed within the for loop so that you can avoid creating the verb dictionary altogether? i.e., instead of taking more space by creating a new dictionary

Since the format of dictionary_verbs is such that we need two for loops to achieve what you need it is time-consuming to iterate over it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand, but only for the way you expressed yourself and therefore for communication reasons. Can you be clearer in the 2 answers? Thanks and sorry

Comment: You are there? Thank you

Comment: What part of the solution do you need more clarification on?

Comment: The nested_k loop, nested_v in value.items. What is its purpose? What does he do? Then I didn't understand what you meant by "If the format of the dictionary cant be changed, and you are not looking for optimizing time or space complexity this will print what you are looking for"? ". looking for optimizing time or space complexity this will print what you are looking for "? You answered me, but I didn't understand. I read with the Google translator which is not very clear. So if you can write a comment a little clearer

Comment: edited the answer and tried to answer it to the best of my capacity. thanks

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you. A curiosity: you wrote that you suggest to use a different structure / format for the dictionary "dictionary_verbs. Which one do you recommend for example? How could I do it? Thanks

Comment: i would suggest
dictionary_verbs = { "chiamare": {"female" : { "singular" : "è chiamata"},
                                  "male": {"singular": "è chiamato"}},}
so that second loop can be avoided

Comment: Also If the answer works for you, can you please accept the answer. thanks :)